# Can an observer have zero time component of 4-velocity?

Tags: general-relativity, velocity, event-horizon, observers, hawking-radiation

I’ve been working through Schutz’s First Course in GR. In chapter 11 (second edition page 324), he does a rough calculation relating to Hawking radiation. To calculate the energy relative to an observer inside the event horizon he chooses an observer on a trajectory with $p_0=0=U^0=0$ (Schwarzschild metric).
The only definition of 4 velocity of which I am aware has $U^0=\frac{dt}{d\tau}$ and I don’t see how this becomes zero.

Answer (score 1):

The key point is from the sentence before the one you're talking about: "Inside the horizon, an observer..."  You're looking for the trajectory of a possible *observer* that is *inside* the horizon.  But $t$ is a spatial coordinate inside the horizon, so it's perfectly fine to just set it to a constant — just as it's okay to set $\theta$ and $\phi$ to constants — which implies $U^0=0$.

Comment: Thanks, sounds plausible! I still haven’t got used to this peculiar way of thinking.

Comment: Oh, he even says "$t$ is a spatial coordinate inside the horizon" a little lower down.  :)

Comment: All right, don’t rub it in!